# Bootstrap 3 - same height for 4 columns applied to div-body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I went through all other related BS3 posts in regards to aligning the height for all grid columns, but none of this seems to help with my particular scenario.

**The Problem:**

I am running BS 3 for a project and have 1x row with 4x card divs. the card divs each have a body and footer, where as the amount of text in the body differs for each card but all have the same footer.
What I want to achieve is to set the body height of ALL columns to the the value of the highest column, so that they all look the same no matter the amount of text in the body.

**What I've tried:**

- utilizing flex, but doesnt seem to work on BS3

  ```
   .row.equal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  ```
- [negative padding and margins](http://www.bootply.com/6mwUqfimQN) applied to `row`, `card` and `card-body` elements
- mucked around with a third party CSS that supposedly runs `flex` on BS3 but also didn't do the trick

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Content area -->
<div class="content">

    <!-- Inner container -->
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column flex-md-row">

        <!-- Left content -->
        <div class="w-100 overflow-auto order-2 order-md-1">

            <!-- Grid -->
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-img-actions">
                                <a href="./gallery/IMG_' . $row['image_id'] . '.jpeg" data-lightbox="Modeabverkauf" class="md-opjjpmhoiojifppkkcdabiobhakljdgm_doc">
                                    <img src="./gallery/thumbs/IMG_' . $row['image_id'] . '.jpeg" class="card-img" width="96" alt="' . $row['image_id'] . '">
                                    <span class="card-img-actions-overlay card-img">
                                        <i class="icon-ico-plus icon-2x"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body bg-light text-center">
                            <div class="mb-2">
                                <h6 class="font-weight-semibold mb-0">
                                    <div class="text-default">' . $row['type'] . ' [#' . $row['image_id'] . ']</div>
                                </h6>

                                <div class="text-muted">
                                    Label: ' . $row['label'] . '
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-muted">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-muted">
                                    <i>' . utf8_encode($row['description']) . '</i>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h3 class="mb-0 font-weight-semibold">' . $price . '</h3>

                            <div class="text-muted mb-3">
                                    Grösse(n): ' . $row['size'] . '<br>
                                    Farbe(n): ' . $row['color'] . '<br>
                                    Anzahl: ' . $row['quantity'] . '
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer bg-light text-center">
                            <button id="btn_' . $row['image_id'] . '" name="btn_' . $row['image_id'] . '" type="button" class="btn bg-teal-400" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_contact_form"><span class="icon-ico-mail4"></span>  Anfragen</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image: Current height layout]

Appreciate any help on this, thank you.

Comment: Post your CSS for us to write an answer!

Comment: @MattAllegro I am using default bootstrap CSS, nothing added there. Didn't try `min-height`, how would I define that one to have the highest value for all divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to reproduce the problem with only partial HTML and no link to your version of BS3 stylesheet and js script. Anyway, in my experience, one (or more) of the following should solve.

Try:

```
.card {min-height:300px}
```

or, more probably:

```
.w-100 .col-xl-3, .w-100 .col-sm-6 {min-height:300px}
```

Instead of `300px`, type the max value of the height of the column cells (`col-xl-3`/`col-sm-6`) that you can get from your browser console. For example, if the `height` of your product cells ranges from 381px to 412px, use `min-height:412px`. Tune this value for each of your CSS media queries.

This is how I handled the *same* problem on BS3 quite many times in the past. Please comment if this applies or not! :)

Comment: Thank you Matt, the styling applied to the `.card` class did the trick, I had to play around and add another `<section id="abc">` element since the styling applies to all cards, but all in all it worked perfectly. Thank you.